# Too large number coming from fortran: ValueError: Could not convert string to float: '0.22738+109'

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, fortran, log-likelihood

I'm am trying to extract real values coming from a fortran file using `np.loadtxt`, the name of the file is `fort.31`
It seems a number is not taken into account by python: `0.22738+109`

Do you have any idea on how to get over it?

Here is my code

```
vraisemblance2d=np.loadtxt("fort.31")
```

And here is the complete error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "plots3d.py", line 28, in <module> 
   vraisemblance2d=np.loadtxt("fort.31") 
 File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1146, in loadtxt 
   for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize): 
 File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1074, in read_data 
   items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)] 
 File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1074, in <listcomp> 
   items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)] 
 File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 781, in floatconv 
   return float(x) 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.22738+109'
```

Comment: This is a huge number (almost the number of atoms in the universe).
Can you scale the numbers without effecting your result or do you have to use this number? for example using log*?

Comment: I have tried, and i obtain some Nan (Not a number) in fort.31
Which are not really usable

Comment: The magnitude of the number isn't the problem; `float` can produce double floats, which have a maximum magnitude of about 1e308. The problem is that the letter `e` is missing; it should be `0.22738e+109`. How was the file created? Are all of the numbers in the file missing the `e`? If you cannot regenerate the file, you might need to resort to string operations in Python, i.e. parse the parts of the number and glue it back together with the `e`, and then apply `float`.

Comment: Do you know the `shape` of the input array before you load it?  Or at least how many columns?

Comment: The file was created  using the following fortran line
WRITE(31,'(G12.5,G12.5,G12.5,2XG12.5)') x,y,z,max(like,1.e-20)
where x,y,z describe a regular mesh and the likelihood (like)

The likelihood takes some values without an e, e.g. 0.17556+139 or 0.14270+309 or even Infinity...

How is it possible to have those numbers encoded right?

Comment: OK, assume I know nothing about `fortran` - do you know how many columns you have?  Sounds like 3, or maybe 5?

Comment: @DanielF There are 4 columns and 64 481 201 lines...

Answer (score 0):

OK, four columns.  I know nothing about `fortran`, so I'm just going to handle it on the `python` side.  I'm assuming `utf` encoding but that might need to be tuned:

```
conv =  lambda x: float("e+".join(x.split("+")))   
vraisemblance2d = np.loadtxt("fort.31", 
                             converters = {i : conv for i in range(4)},
                             encoding   = "utf-8")
```

If that doesn't work, and `fortran` is giving you a mix of `#.###+###` and `#.###e+###` format, you'll need regex.

```
import re

reg = re.compile('(\d\.\d+)\+(\d+)')

def conv(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return float("e+".join(reg.match(x).groups())) 

vraisemblance2d = np.loadtxt("fort.31", 
                             converters = {i : conv for i in range(4)},
                             encoding   = "utf-8")
```

WARNING: I am no `regex` wizard, there's probably a better & faster way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i get two errors

Here is the first error

Traceback (most recent call last): 
 Huge blablabla
 File "plots3d.py", line 28, in <lambda> 
   conv = lambda x: float("e+".join(x.split("+"))) 
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Here is the second

File "plots3d.py", line 23, in conv 
   return float(("e+".join(reg.match(x).groups()))) 
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Oh man, what `python` version are you using?

Comment: Here is the answer of sys.version

3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0]

Comment: Oh wait, it's `loadtxt` outputting `bytes` for compatibility to old `python`.  Check  edit.

Comment: Yes, i do not know how to apply the function to the file. loadtxt allowed me to have the output

Comment: That last dupe target has a recipe for `np.genfromtext`, I'd say use that

Comment: np.genfromtxt("fort.31") is Killed..